# Convert list of strings to int

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

I have a list of strings that I want to convert to int, or have in int from the start.

The task is to extract numbers out of a text (and get the sum). What I did was this:

```
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    z = re.findall("\d+",line)
    if len(z)>0:
        lst.append(z)
print (z)
```

Which gives me a list like `[['5382', '1399', '3534'], ['1908', '8123', '2857']`. I tried `map(int,...` and one other thing, but I get errors such as:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [[int(x) for x in sublist] for sublist in lst]
[[5382, 1399, 3534], [1908, 8123, 2857]]
```

or map

```
>>> [map(int, sublist) for sublist in lst]
[[5382, 1399, 3534], [1908, 8123, 2857]]
```

or just change your line

```
lst.append(z)
```

to

```
lst.append(map(int, z))
```

The reason why your map did not work is that you tried to apply `int` to every list of your list of lists, not to every element of every sublist.

**update** for Python3 users:

In Python3, `map` will return a map object which you have to cast back to a list manually, i.e. `list(map(int, z))` instead of `map(int, z)`.

Comment: Thanks, this explains a lot :) However, when I use map for append, all I get in the output is [<map object at 0x02EADCD0> etc. – do you have any ideas for how I could go about getting the output in a single list or merging lists so I can use all the numbers? Thank you!

Comment: @erocoar ah, that's because you are using Python3. In Python3, `map` will return a map object which you have to cast back to a list manually, i.e. `list(map(int, z))` instead of `map(int, z)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the whole input and use a regular expression:

```
import sys
import re

numbers = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', sys.stdin.read()))
print numbers, sum(numbers)
```

On input

```
11 22
33
```

The output is

```
[11, 22, 33] 66
```

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me what the r in front of  `r'\d+'` means, and how to use `sys.stdin.read()`? I have no idea how that command works, never mind how to open my txt file with it. Thanks :)

Comment: It's a way of simplifying writing regular expressions. With `r` you say for example that backslash doesn't need to be escaped. So instead of writing '\\d+' we can just write r'\d+'

Comment: @JuniorCompressor '\d+' will work perfectly fine without the r prefix, there is no \d escape sequence. `'\\d' == '\d'` is `True`. The r prefix is helpful when you have stuff like `'\n'` or `'\t'` in your regex.